# For-loop over dictionary fails if dictionary is empty

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm learning Python and I've come across something I can't figure out myself.

I have a text file `mbox-short.txt` with lines like:

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.90])

From louis@media.berkeley.edu Fri Jan  4 18:10:48 2008
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.97])

From zqian@umich.edu Fri Jan  4 16:10:39 2008
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.25])
```

The following code works fine:

```
x = open('mbox-short.txt')
y = dict()
count = int()
for line in x:                     # read every line of <file>
    if line.startswith('From '):   # check if <line> starts with <'From '>
        line1 = line.split(' ')    # split <line> into separate words -> <line1>
        count = count + 1          # count every <'From '> occurence
        w = line1[1]               # 2nd word of <line1>
        if w not in y:             # check if 2nd word of <line1>(=w) is already in dict <y>
            y[w] = 1               # add 2nd word of <line1> as key with <value>=1 
        else:
            y[w] += 1              # or +1 to <value>
print(y)
```

It works even when at the start `y` is still an empty dict.

Output:

```
{'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za': 2, 'louis@media.berkeley.edu': 3, ... 'ray@media.berkeley.edu': 1}
```

In the tutorial I'm working with there is another example, using the `.get` method:

```
word = 'brontosaurus'
d = dict()
for c in word:
    d[c] = d.get(c,0) + 1
print(d)
```

When I try that:

```
x = 'file'
y = dict()
count = int()
for line in x:                     # read every line of <file>
    if line.startswith('From '):   # check if <line> starts with <'From '>
        line1 = line.split(' ')    # split <line> into separate words -> <line1>
        count = count + 1          # count every <'From '> occurence
        w = line1[1]               # 2nd word of <line1>
        for w in y:                # alternate + simplified form using <dict.get> method
            y[w] = y.get(w,0) + 1  # check if <w> is already in dict y, if not, add it
print(y)
```

It fails. Output:

```
{}
```

Using the debugger I can see that the `for w in y:` loop is not executed. It just jumps out at `y`.

I don't understand why.

Comment: If `y` is empty, what do you expect `for w in y:` to do? There’s nothing to iterate over.

Comment: I don't see where you opened the file you want to read. You open file using `open`

Comment: Yes it’s not an [mre] - please edit your code so someone could paste it into a file and run it __without adding anything else__

Comment: That's not how you read from files. See 'Iterating Over Each Line in the File' at https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/#reading-and-writing-opened-files

Comment: @barny - can't figure out how to make a minimal reproducible example of my code, just to dumb :-(

Comment: The line `y[w] = y.get(w,0) + 1` counts how often `w` occurs in the dict `y`. The `get()` method will not fail with an error in case `w` has not yet been encountered and thus `y[w]` does not yet exist. Instead, it returns `0` so that the counter is set to `1`. In the example from the tutorial, letter frequencies are counted but a string is given; so one needs to iterate over the string 'brontosaurus' to extract each letter. For your task, you don't need to iterate over anything, you just count `w` frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for w in y:
    y[w] = y.get(w,0) + 1
```

I don't know why you've added the first line.

If `y` is empty at the beginning, `for w in y` will iterate over the dictionary zero times, and the second line will never be executed, so nothing will be added to the dictionary, which is why it prints `{}` at the end.

`y.get(w, 0)` already means: "check if `w` is in `y`, if so give me `y[w]`, otherwise give me 0".

You don't need an `if` and no `for` loop here.

Just change these two lines to:

```
 y[w] = y.get(w,0) + 1
```

Comment: Thx for your constructive answer. When I went to bed yesterday I thought this through and had the very same brainwave. I tried it in the morning and it worked (of course) but had to rush to work, so I couldn't have a look here.
Seems one gets blind if staring too long at one point :-)